# cryptography hardware acceleration with GPU

Tags: encryption, cuda, openssl, hardware

Does anybody use Nvidia CUDA based solutions for SSL/AES acceleration in production?
I'm interesting in SSL offload and AES encryption/decryption acceleration.

I found few open-source solutions like engine-cuda. [Benchmarks are pretty impressive](http://code.google.com/p/engine-cuda/wiki/benchmarkVersion011).
But I still in doubt if it useful in a real production system.

Possible cons are:

- third party open source solutions aren't mature enough for production use
- it's not so effective as on synthetic tests
- is it easily integrated with scripting languages or I will be forced to fork openssl

Comment: I evaluated few dedicated hardware solutions. None of them worths its' money. I've tried cudamrg engine in openssl with 5-year old card. It does AES at half of speed of 1 i7 core. If you extrapolate this card performance to modern high end NVIDIA commodity GPU GTX 6xx you could have 100x improvement. The question is -- does this extrapolation fairly?

Comment: Sergey, can you comment on what dedicated hardware solutions you tried out? I'm interested to know since we wrote a GPU encryption SDK (gkrypt.com) which does 10GBps (capital B) on a single Tesla K20 or equivalent GeForce series card) of AES-256. Would love to discuss it with you.

Comment: Salman, I tested Exar DX1740. AES encryption throughput was about 3Gbps (lowercase b). But the card itself is very small and not power greedy. You could put 10 of them in one motherboard without problems with cooling. In terms of Gbps/rack_unit/price it was better than i7 2 years ago (2012).

Answer (score 6):

I don't use CUDA for acceleration, but I don't think AES is the algorithm you should optimize in SSL. AES was designed to be very efficient in software, and newest Intel processors have even [specialized instructions](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-advanced-encryption-standard-aes-instructions-set/) to carry out a full round of AES completely in hardware.

Additionally, some [recent attacks](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/09/man-in-the-midd_4.html) have also pushed many sites to switch the preferred cipher suite from AES to RC4, and RC4 even faster in software.

In SSL, the most time consuming operation has historically always been the RSA private key decryption(s) that the server must do during the initial handshake and for most cipher suites. That is one of the reasons that led to the availability on the market of so many HW accelerators for e-commerce websites in the late '90s. RSA decryption in software is very slow, and that limits the load each website can sustain, that is, the number of TCP/SSL connections per seconds.

As far as I can tell, there has been some [academic research](https://www.cs.tcd.ie/John.Waldron/owenHarrison/publications/PKonGPU_eurocrypt.pdf) on the topic. GPUs can effectively speed up RSA (or more precisely, modular exponentiation with large integers), but not by a surprisingly large factor. Additionally, latency may also be a problem depending on the graphic card model you have. I cannot find much open source software for executing RSA in GPUs though, let alone any one that integrates into an SSL stack like openssl.

Comment: You seem to have missed [SSLShader](http://shader.kaist.edu/sslshader/sslshader.pdf) which has a published [working library implementation](http://shader.kaist.edu/sslshader/libgpucrypto/)

Answer (score 0):

There is evidence that serious encryption should NOT use hardware cryptography instructions proposed by Intel and VIA chips. Following Snowden's leaks, the random numbers generated by such hardware may have reduced entropy and thus not that secure as claimed! For more info: http://bit.ly/IDkRVq

Comment: The crypto instructions referenced in that article are "black box" instructions that can generate seed data for pseudo-random number generators, and are distinct from the AES-NI acceleration operations, which are well-understood and just fine.